# Including jQuery into my typo3 extension issues

Tags: jquery, typo3, typo3-8.x

Currently I'm on progress to migrate all my typo3 6.2.31 extensions to 8.7.

I've got some questions reguarding using jQuery in my backend plugin.

Do I have to include jQuery or is it automatically imported from Typo3 8.7?

If yes do I have to use the `$` or `jQuery` as selector?

At the moment I got this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tablesorter is not a function
   at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (VM2139 global.js:68)
   at j (VM2124 jquery-1.11.2.min.js:2)
   at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (VM2124 jquery-1.11.2.min.js:2)
   at Function.ready (VM2124 jquery-1.11.2.min.js:2)
   at HTMLDocument.J (VM2124 jquery-1.11.2.min.js:2)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This sounded familiar, so I did a quick search. Turns out you asked the same question last year for an upgrade to TYPO3 7.6 and answered it yourself. Did you try the same thing now? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46583930/uncaught-typeerror-jquery-tablesorter-is-not-a-function

Comment: :) amazing thats the biggest fail since I'm active on stack overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jquery is usally always loaded in backend modules, you can use $. The tablesorter plugin is however afaik not a default, you may need to load / register that one. You may find examples in the core, for instance the extension manager loads the datatables plugin.

On view helper level, the inclusion of jQuery by default has been documented with https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/8.7/Deprecation-80047-DeprecateJQueryAndExtJSForBEViewhelpers.html

Tipp: Go to the install tool "upgrade analysis" and search for jquery.

If you are dealing with extbase based plugins, the PermissionController of core extension be_user could be a relatively simple place to look at how core extensions solve backend modules in v8.

Answer (score 1):

Thist question might be the same as yours, and maybe the answers can help you

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52204283/6796558

I marked your question as duplicate due to the fact mentioned above.

Comment: If you believe a question has already been answered elsewhere, please vote to close it as a duplicate instead of answering it

Comment: Hi @RoryMcCrossan - I marked it as duplicate while answering with a link. That gave the person a chance to find the answer via the link, untill the peer review would accept it as duplicated.

Comment: That's what comments are for.